# Show if $p^n(i,j)\rightarrow \pi(j)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ then $\pi(j)$ is a stationary measure..

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose $p(i,j)$ is a transition kernel on $S$ for a countable state markov chain $X_n$ with $$p^n(i,j)\rightarrow \pi(j)$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for all $i,j\in S$. want to verify that $\pi$ is a stationary measure with respect to $p$.

We need to verify that $$\sum_i \pi(i)p(i,j)=p(j).$$

I am having trouble showing this directly. I have an inequality, but am not sure how to get equality.

$$\sum_i \pi(i)p(i,j)
=\sum_i \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p^n(k,i)p(i,j)\leq\liminf_n\sum_i p^n(k,i)p(i,j)=\liminf_n p^{n+1}(k,j)=\pi(j)$$

Where the inequality is by Fatou, and the second last equality is because of Chapman-Kolmogorov. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the equality $$\sum_j\sum_i\pi(i)p(i,j)=\sum_i\pi(i)\sum_jp(i,j)=1=\sum_j\pi(j)$$ would be violated if the inequality in your proof was strict.

Comment: *if even only one of the inequalities in your proof was strict.

Comment: That seems a bit too powerful of a result. It's unsettling haha. But thank you very much!